# Express await database connection

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am following a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142495/node-js-async-await-module-export)

I am struggling with awaiting the module import from my express application.

I understand that to use await, it must be wrapped in an async function. However I can't wrap my entire node program in an async function because it will exit without doing anything useful.

How can I properly await the database connection?

**node/express:**

```
require('dotenv').config();
var express = require('express');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login/login');
var app = express();

async() => {
    const { client } = await require('./db/db');
    app.use('/login', loginRouter);
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.listen(app.get('port'));
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
}
```

**db module:**

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

module.exports = (async() => {
    const client = new Client();
    await client.connect();
    return { client };
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to export a `Promise` that resolves to a *connected* `client`. Then, when you import it, call `.then` on the imported `Promise` to get to the connected client:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client();
module.exports = {
  clientProm: client.connect().then(() => client)
};
```

And:

```
const { clientProm } = require('./db/db');
clientProm.then((client) => {
  // do stuff with connected client
});
```

Comment: I have my routes in different modules as well. When I import this module into those route modules, how can I persist the database connection without creating a new one Everytime? And am I able to just wrap all my route endpoints with the .then function in each module?

Comment: After rereading it my second question is answered. I didn't see we pass the client as a parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue - the connected client `Promise` exported from the DB module will reference the same object everywhere it's imported

Comment: I really like this solution. Thank you