# Export async config module node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, module, export

In my project i want to use *puppeteer* and share it across multiple files. I want to store it as config file where i can export it and get my `page` variable. Problem with that is when I am importing that by `require()` it returns a me promise with status pending. What is then the solve?

```js
// configFile.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  return page;
})();
```

```js
const page = require('./configFile'); // Promise { <pending> }
```

How to resolve that promise before it can be exported? Is there an await for `module.exports`?

Answer (score 0):

`const page = await require("yourmodule");`

please look here possible duplicate: [Node.js Async/Await module export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142495/node-js-async-await-module-export)

Comment: Yes that helped me, i wrapped it in an async function and it does the work. Thank you!