# creating desposit method but got card.save is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

> TypeError: card.save is not a function at exports.deposit

transaction controller

```js
const Transaction = require('../models/transaction');
const Card = require('../models/cards');


exports.deposit = (req, res) => {
   const {amount} = req.body 
   
   const card = Card.findOne({user: req.profile})

   if(card){
    card.balance = card.balance + amount
    card.save()
   }
   res.status(400).json({error: 'Card not found'})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose is asynchronous so you need to add async/await.

```
export const deposit = async (req, res) => {
   const {amount} = req.body 
   
   const card = await Card.findOne({user: req.profile})

   if(card){
    card.balance = card.balance + amount
    card.save()
   }
   res.status(400).json({error: 'Card not found'})
}
```

Since you need to use promises, you may need to rework your moduling login if you want to use commonJS. I'm using ES6 syntaxes above.

You may be able to find some answers with regards to that here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/51142584/2822041

Alternatively you can use callback

```
export const deposit = (req, res) => {
   const {amount} = req.body 
   
   Card.findOne({user: req.profile}, (card) => {
     if(card){
        card.balance = card.balance + amount
        card.save()
     }
   res.status(400).json({error: 'Card not found'})

   })

   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to know if this is possible without add async/await. I would have loved to use JS

Comment: I forgot, you can use callback too -> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Answer (score 0):

After much time, I got it with this code

```js
exports.deposit = (req, res) => {
    const {amount, cardId} = req.body 
    
    const card = Card.findOne({user: req.profile._id, _id: cardId})
        .exec((error, card) => {
            if(error) return res.status(400).json({error});
            if(card){
                card.balance = card.balance + amount
            }

            card.save((error, card) => {
                if(error) return res.status(400).json({error});
                if(card){
                    return res.status(201).json({ card});
                }
            });
        })
};
```

but, the balance combines the deposit instead of incrementing. Example

I initially deposit amount = 200 and balance becomes 200

However, at my next deposit of 300, balance should be 500. But the balance output is 200300.

I will appreciate your help