# I keep seeing await require is OK, but I cannot make it work

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, node-modules

Ok, so there are answers here such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142495/node-js-async-await-module-export) that state that I should be able to export a promise and then await on said promise whenever I `require` the module.  Well, I cannot make it work.  I always get the error message *SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules*.  But guess what:  As far as I can tell I am putting in at the top level of a module!

Here's some code:

```js
const wjConfig = require('wj-config');
const fs = require('fs');

const loadJsonFile = (fileName, isRequired) => {
    const fileExists = fs.existsSync(fileName);
    if (fileExists) {
        const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }
    else if (isRequired) {
        throw new Error(`Configuration file ${fileName} is required but was not found.`);
    }
    // Return an empty object.
    return {};
};

const env = new wjConfig.Environment(process.env.NODE_ENV);
const config = wjConfig()
    .addObject(loadJsonFile('./config/config.json', true))
    .name('Main Configuration')
    .addObject(loadJsonFile(`./config/config.${env.value}.json`))
    .name('Env Configuration')
    .addEnvironment(process.env)
    .includeEnvironment(env)
    .createUrlFunctions()
    .includeValueTrace()
    .build();

// Is this not part of the top level of this module??
module.exports = await config;
```

I have also done `const config = await wjConfig()` with the same result.

I have also tried removing `await` from this `config.js` module and putting it in the main entry point file `index.js`.  Same error.  Bottomline:  No matter where I put the `await`, I cannot make this work.  Any pointers?

I am using NodeJS v18.1.0.  Many thanks.

Comment: @JaromandaX, so contrary to the text of the error message, await is invalid at the top level of a module??

Comment: @JaromandaX while I appreciate your help, I cannot help to detect a condescending tone in your responses.  If you are annoyed by questions, maybe you should take a vacation from answering.  The error message clearly states the opposite and does not make the note that it only applies to ES modules, not commonjs modules.  You might want to work on this.  Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Wow.  Nuff said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top level, you can only use `await` in ESM modules (that use `import` not `require()`), not in CommonJS modules which is what your code is.

So, as long as your code is in a CommonJS module, you can't use `await` at the top level.

As for the error message:

***SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules***

That is indeed not entirely clear.  Apparently when they say "modules", they mean `type: "module"` as one would specify it in package.json which is an ESM module, not a CommonJS module.

It could also be that this error message is from the V8 JS engine where the error messages are targeted more at the browser environment where the only type of Javascript "module" in the browser is an ESM module as there is no other type of "module" in a browser.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Indeed the message is confusing for us developers that are not used to this "modules war".  We see the word "module" and do not associate it to the ES Module specification immediately.  Basically one has to resort to IIFE's and async functions inside `then()` calls to work around all this in CommonJS.  My concern was Express, but I just tested and was able to convert the express-generator template to ES Modules.  I think I'll work based on this assumption.